# Mobile Text Input Zoom

Tags: html, css, mobile, materialize

I realise this has been asked and answered many many times, but none of the solutions I have found are working for me.

The problem is that when viewing the web app on a mobile, the autozoom focuses on the `text-input` for the user to type. The standard ios zoom into form elements.

I am using Materialize CSS delivered through the cdn link.

I have tried all of the options of the viewport scale I could find and I have tried setting font to min 16px for all of the individual elements and also `* {font-size: 16px !important;}`. This changes the font size, but the zoom still happens.

I have used `@media`  in the CSS to scale the buttons on a small screen which looks good, I wonder if I need to do something with this for my `text-input`?

The only other thing I can think of, but I really know nothing about it is using `-webkit-`.

This is an internal business app for a specific function, so it doesn't overly matter, it has become more a matter of principle. As always any help really appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is please? Also, put example code into your question which we can run to see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

On further playing around changing the global font size to `* {font-size: 36px !important;}` solves the issue. I think anything over 32px worked. A bit of a workaround but good for my purposes.